# ImportError: cannot import name convert_all_kernels_in_model

Tags: python, imageai

I am trying to use ImageAI’s model training to train an AI model.

This is the code:

```
 from imageai.Prediction.Custom import ModelTraining
 model_trainer = ModelTraining()
 model_trainer.setModelTypeAsResNet()
 model_trainer.setDataDirectory("idenprof")
 model_trainer.trainModel(num_objects=2, num_experiments=3, enhance_data=True, 
 batch_size=32, show_network_summary=True)
```

This is the error I get when running:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../FirstTraining.py", line 1, in <module>
    from imageai.Prediction.Custom import ModelTraining
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/imageai/Prediction/Custom/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..DenseNet.densenet import DenseNetImageNet121
  File ".../PycharmProjects/bonez/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/imageai/Prediction/DenseNet/densenet.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import convert_all_kernels_in_model
ImportError: cannot import name convert_all_kernels_in_model
```

I have searched all over but I could not find the same issue or a way to solve the problem. I have the following dependencies installed: Tensorflow, OpenCV, Keras, and ImageAI.

Answer (score 6):

Update: It turns out ImageAI does not support Tensorflow 2 yet. This issue does not happen with following tensorflow version: `pip install tensorflow==1.15.2`

---

I had the same issue and resolved it by replacing all `tensorflow.python.keras` imports with `tensorflow.keras` in ImageAI library. After this, `from imageai.Prediction.Custom import ModelTraining` import works fine.

If you want to follow, there is an open issue for problem in ImageAI: https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/issues/494

Comment: Hi Ali, could you elaborate what you mean by "replacing all `tensorflow.python.keras` imports..."? I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: @F16Falcon basically find and replace every `tensorflow.python.keras` with `tensorflow.keras` in the ImageAI code that you installed with pip.

Comment: I changed all instances of tensorflow.python.keras to tensorflow.keras and now I have this error output: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 329, in compile
    raise ValueError('`tf.compat.v1.keras` Optimizer (', optimizer, ') is '
ValueError: ('`tf.compat.v1.keras` Optimizer (', <tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers.Adam object at 0x1391ef9d0>, ') is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use a `tf.keras` Optimizer instead, or disable eager execution.')

Comment: @sydney I added new information to the answer. Looks like downgrading tensorflow to 1.* version fixes the issue

Comment: Apparently 1.15.2 is no longer available?

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15.2 (from versions: 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0, 2.11.1, 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0, 2.12.1, 2.13.0rc0, 2.13.0rc1, 2.13.0rc2, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.14.0rc0, 2.14.0rc1, 2.14.0, 2.14.1, 2.15.0rc0, 2.15.0rc1, 2.15.0, 2.15.0.post1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15.2